# Django - How to get value of radio button?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

I'm creating quiz application, where user answers multiple choice questions and gets score. I've created everything, except calculating score. For this I should get value from radio buttons which user selected and compare it with correct answer. The problem is that, I can't get this value. Here are my codes:

`models.py`:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(_('Sualın mətni'), max_length=250)
    option_a = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    option_b = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    option_c = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    option_d = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    answer = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
```

`views.py`:

```
def index(request):
    questions = Question.objects.all()
    context = {
        'questions': questions,
    }
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

`html`:

```
<div class="main-container">
    {% for question in questions %}
    <div class="question-box">
        <div class="question-text">
            <p>{{ question.question_text }}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="question-answers">
            <input class="option" type="radio" name="{{ question.id }}" value="{{ question.option_a }}">
            <label>{{ question.option_a }}</label>

            <input class="option" type="radio" name="{{ question.id }}" value="{{ question.option_b }}">
            <label>{{ question.option_b }}</label>

            <input class="option" type="radio" name="{{ question.id }}" value="{{ question.option_c }}">
            <label>{{ question.option_c }}</label>

            <input class="option" type="radio" name="{{ question.id }}" value="{{ question.option_d }}">
            <label>{{ question.option_d }}</label>

        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" value="End quiz">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
question.option_a
question.option_b
question.option_c
question.option_d
```

These variables hold the values as True or False

Comment: Nope, they hold texts. They are `CharField`.